# remove mobile menu when list item is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my first question so apologies if not following standard practice.

I need help with this mobile nav menu. I got the code of the below youtube video. The issue is, while it is a good attempt at a pure CSS mobile nav, the menu does not auto remove when a list item is clicked.

```css
.nav {
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
  text-align: right;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(66,65,65);
  background: grey;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.menu a {
  clear: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-size: 2em;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

label {
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 70px;
  display: none;
  width: 26px;
  float: right;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

  @media (max-width: 850px) { 
    .ml14 {
      font-size: 5em;
    }
    label {
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .menu {
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      display: none;
    }
    
    .menu a {
      display: block;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
      margin: 0;
      background: rgb(66,65,65);
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(180, 180, 180) 0%, rgba(231,221,221,1) 72%);
    }

    #toggle:checked ~ .menu {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="nav">
        <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
        <div class="menu">
            <a class="section1" href="#">About</a>
            <a class="contact-sec" href="#">Contact</a>
            <a class="section3" href="#">Gallery</a>   
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-5x"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Codepen with menu](https://codepen.io/James_Baird/pen/OJyrQwE)

[Youtube video showing original source of menu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMTs8tAapnQ&lc=z22tyt2rsmj1xxnbu04t1aokg2ahv45g0ennk5mljoodrk0h00410.1589925648681998)

Comment: jquery/js not allowed to resolve?

Comment: I dont use jquery, but happy for JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simple add function when click on link input check will be false and menu close.

```js
function CloseMenu(){
 document.getElementById("toggle").checked = false;
 
 }
```

```css
.nav {
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
  text-align: right;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(66,65,65);
  background: grey;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.menu a {
  clear: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-size: 2em;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

label {
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 70px;
  display: none;
  width: 26px;
  float: right;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

  @media (max-width: 850px) { 
    .ml14 {
      font-size: 5em;
    }
    label {
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .menu {
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      display: none;
    }
    
    .menu a {
      display: block;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
      margin: 0;
      background: rgb(66,65,65);
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(180, 180, 180) 0%, rgba(231,221,221,1) 72%);
    }

    #toggle:checked ~ .menu {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
        <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
        <div class="menu" id="menu">
            <a class="section1" href="#" onclick="CloseMenu()">About</a>
            <a class="contact-sec" href="#" onclick="CloseMenu()">Contact</a>
            <a class="section3" href="#" onclick="CloseMenu()">Gallery</a>   
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook" onclick="CloseMenu()"></i></a>
            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-5x" onclick="CloseMenu()"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That does remove the menu, but then the menu is permanently deactivated after that??